# Explanation for CVBufferPool with AVAssetWriter?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter

So let's say I want to make a movie from images. I'm told to use `AVAssetWriter`, along with an `AVAssetWriterInput` to append `CVPixelBuffer` objects. But I'm very confused.

Why do we create the pixel buffers, only to create a bitmap context to make a movie, and then draw using `drawRectInViewHierarchy`?

Comment: You either input frames with camera/file add a AVDataOutput, this will output CVPixelBuffers which you can do what you want with, apply filters in real time? transform them, anything

Comment: Is this a question about `CVBufferPool`? Your question doesn't reference it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what information you're basing your question on, but I'll try to explain the basics.

First, `CVPixelBuffer` is a CoreVideo object that stores image data. All of the AVFoundation classes that deal with image data use objects of this type. However, a `CVPixelBuffer` is not a simple object to construct, you can't simply instantiate one from a blob of JPEG or PNG data.

One possible way of creating a `CVPixelBuffer` is by calling `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` from a `CGImageDataProvider`. There are potentially other solutions that might work and/or be more efficient. It depends on what kind of images you're starting with.